# identify sequence in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large list of real numbers, that vary between a maximum and a minimum.
For the sake of an example: `megalist=RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 10^4]`.
Now, I have a much smaller list such as  `minilist={0.3,1,-0.5}` and I would like to see whether `minilist` is contained inside `megalist`, within a certain tolerance on each component of the list, let us say +-0.1.
In other words: whether `megalist` contains a sublist such as: {0.3+-0.1,1+-0.1,-0.5+-0.1}.
And, if it exists, I would like to get its position.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of subsequences of length 3 using `Partition` and use `Nearest` with distance function `ChessboardDistance` (thanks: @CarlWoll ):

```
nF = Nearest[Partition[megalist, 3, 1] -> {"Element", "Index"}, 
  DistanceFunction -> (Norm[# - #2, Infinity] &)]
```

[image]

The function `nF[x]` returns the subsequences of `megalist` and their positions *nearest*  `x`.

There are no subsequences within distance .1 of `minilist`:

```
nF[minilist, {All, .1}]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

There are 2 within distance .25:

```
nF[minilist, {All, .2}]
```

> ```
> {{{0.473371, 1.18655, -0.703937}, 4590}, 
> {{0.473238, 1.2483, -0.690072}, 6032}}
> ```

Comment: I think you can use [`ChessboardDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChessboardDistance) instead.

Comment: Of course! Thank you @Carl. Updated.